# combo bar line chart with multiple grouped/stacked datasets

Tags: combobox, chart.js

there.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.6.2/samples/other-charts/combo-bar-line.html

I'm using ChartJS to make a chart below.
[image]

What I did:  `https://codepen .io/parmonov98/pen/zYPvGaY`

I can't put multiple datasets on half of the chart.
How can I place multiple(line and bars) on half of the chart?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was creating a Y axes for each dataset, what I needed to do is create one Y axes and use it for multiple datasets.

Hopefully will be helpful to someone.